# Plot: How set markers in plot in front of axes

Tags: graphics, plotting, version-7

I draw a plot using `ListPlot`. But I noticed that `PlotMarkers` are 'covered' by the axes; see example below:

[image]

I was trying to use the option `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` but it does not help. 
Below is my full code of this plot. The size of markers has to be as set.

```
ListPlot[{list1, list2},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[60]],
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"Number of non-zero bits", "alpha"},
 Axes -> False,
 LegendShadow -> None,
 LegendSize -> 0.5,
 PlotLegend -> {Style["exact value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130], 
   Style["estimated value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130]},
 LegendPosition -> {0.10, 0.10},
 PlotRange -> {0, 20},
 ImageSize -> 7000,
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

Solution suggested by evanb:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the option

```
PlotRangeClipping -> False
```

Comment: Nice answer. Two Plots showing how it works (before vs. after) would be great.

Comment: I think the question relies on the PlotLegends package, which is deprecated, and also on list1 and list2 which I didn't want to futz around with / make up.  Hence the lack of pictures :)