# Plot markers overlying plot frame instead of underneath?

Tags: plotting, graphics

In the following plot the plot markers are overlain by the plot frame:

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}},
  Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[10, Black, Thickness[0.005]],
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 60},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {50, 50}}
 ]
```

[image]

Is there a straightforward way to move the plot markers to the 'top' layer (i.e. so that the plot markers obscure the frame)?

Previously I have worked around this issue by overlaying two plots using `Show` with the plot 'on top' having no adornments.

[A similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65367/plot-how-set-markers-in-plot-in-front-of-axes) was asked a few years ago and the solution given was to add `PlotRangeClipping -> False` to the plot options. As you can see this doesn't affect the superposition.

I'm using 10.4.4

Comment: `Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}`

Comment: @Kuba Might be worth to mention that this option (together with the related ones for axes,grid,...) are documented in the Details section of `Graphics`

Comment: @LukasLang only recently, but yes I added a second link.